# How to Highlight SwiftUI Element Being Watched in Vision Pro?

Tags: swiftui, visionos, vision-pro

How to make drag and drop more user friendly in Vision Pro? When user look on an element before the drag starts some indication should exist that a certain element is looked and it is ready for dragging. How can I add a "mouse over" like feature?

I have element like this on the surface, in the space:

```swift
HStack {
    // Your content here
}
.padding(10) // Add padding for better visual indication
.background(
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8) // Add a background shape
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue.opacity(0.3)) // Change color and opacity as needed
)
.onDrag {
    // ..
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: "YourDraggedData" as NSItemProviderWriting)
    return itemProvider
}
.onDrop(of: [UTType.text], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
    // ..
    return true
}
```

Comment: There is no way to know what the user is looking at, Apple actually mentions this when the Vision Pro was introduced. It is a selling point. HoverEffectComponent is the closet thing.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hovereffectcomponent